# How long are unposted questions stored?

Tags: support, draft

How long is an unasked question stored?  By unasked, I mean it was written, there's a preview, but that the "post your question" button was never clicked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Drafts are stored for a week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/).

Actually, for some time they expired after 3 days instead of advertised 7, but [this was fixed in July](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236634/).